# c# Dropbox async Task error

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

Im trying to write a simple c# dropbox application but I'm not too familiar with the System.Threading functions. I have the following code piece:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DropboxClient dbx = new DropboxClient(accessString);
        var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)Run(dbx)); //COMPILE ERROR HERE
        task.Wait();

    }
    static async Task Run(DropboxClient dbx)
    {
        FullAccount full = await dbx.Users.GetCurrentAccountAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", full.Name.DisplayName, full.Email);
        await ListRootFolder(dbx);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have the following error which I cannot figure out:

```
Error   CS0030  Cannot convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>
```

Hopefully a simple fix.
Thanks is advance

Comment: `Task.Run(() => Run(dbx)`

Comment: Easy fix - Thanks so much! :)

Comment: But don't forget to take some tutorial about Task ;-)